# Two XML files looks different

Tags: xml

I am going through the [following](http://www.geckoboard.com/developers/custom-widgets/beginners-guide) documentation and have added the XML file [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2tqtvxtxedgh3qi/visitors.xml):

The XML file mentioned in the documentation looks like [this](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/512939/GB/Examples/visitors.xml) , however, the one I have uploaded looks different. I believe this is the reason I am unable to load the data into my widget. Could anyone tell me why the two XML files looks different? How can I make my XML file look like the one in the documentation?

File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <item>
        <value>123</value>
        <text></text>
    </item>
    <item>
        <value>238</value>
        <text></text>
    </item>
</root>
```

Comment: Please include the xml files in-line (within code blocks) rather than using an external link.

Comment: @BroSlow Included the file !

Answer (score 0):

The two files are identical as far as XML is concerned. `<text/>` is the same thing as `<text></text>`.

Answer (score 0):

All I can say is the  in the other file doesn't have an opening tag, also no XML version or text encoding is shown.

Answer (score 0):

Your files are identical. The problem (*if you are using the dropbox link you posted here, is that that is a dropbox page that contains the xml.. it is not a direct link to the xml file*)

Try linking your widget to the direct link to the file (https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/2tqtvxtxedgh3qi/visitors.xml)

Comment: How can I myself make my uploaded link look like the one mentioned in the link you mentioned? Because I need to do the same for my other XML files.

Comment: @john, one way is to put it in you `public` dropbox folder and then get the share link, or alternatively go to the page you posted and copy the link from the ***download -> direct download*** button